# Do the first k elements of DFT (Xn) correspond to k lowest frequency components?

Tags: fft, time-frequency, time-series

Do the result of DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) of a 1D sequence order as low frequency to high frequency? and why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, the output of a DFT routine is a vector that starts at frequency = 0 and goes up from there.

That's just by convention, however.  If you write an FFT algorithm for $N = 2^m$ points, one "natural" ordering for its output is at frequencies in the sequence $0,  \frac{F_s}{2}, \frac{F_s}{4}, \frac{3F_s}{4}, \cdots, \frac{(N - 1)F_s} N$ (i.e., as if it were addressed by an $m$-bit word in bit-reversed order).

Note that **it's a pretty strong convention**.
All of the common math packages will take such any such penultimate result and reorder it into the conventional ordering.  I don't think I've run across one that doesn't, and I don't think that one that *did* go against this established convention would gain much traction in the marketplace of ideas.

Comment: is it same convention when doing Wavelet Transform or other transform?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the result of the DFT of a 1D sequence is commonly ordered from low frequency to high frequency.  The signal's slowest parts are represented by the low-frequency components, while the high-frequency components represent its fastest-changing parts. Hence, arranging this way makes the resulting frequency spectrum easier to interpret.